# An issue with the difference between natural numbers when they represent the number of elements of sets

Tags: arithmetic

For example, we have a PDF document with 13 chapters and we want only to print chapters 6 to 13. Then, one could think that the number of chapters that would be printed is 13 - 6 = 7, but the real number is 8.

I see that 6 and 13 would represent the number of elements between the sets $\{1,2,...,6\}$ and $\{1,2,...,13\}$, respectively, and that $\{1,2,...,6\} - \{1,2,...,6\}=\{6,7,..., 13\}$. Where is the problem? How could be it explained easily to kids so they know how to do with problems like the example above?

Comment: subtraction only includes 1 endpoint not both.

Comment: Subtracting five from everything, we see that there are as many chapters from six to $13$ as from one to eight, which is obviously eight.

Comment: Any thoughts on any of the comments/answers, Asd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English: When the range is from m to n inclusive, m must of course be part of the range.  The problem is, when you take 1..m away from 1..n, you are *taking m out of the range*.  You have to add it back in.  Hence the size of the range m..n is NOT (m - n), it is (m - n + 1).

Comment: I think you mean $n-m+1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\{1,2,\ldots,6\} - \{1,2,\ldots,6\}=\emptyset\neq\{6,7,\ldots, 13\}$$
$$\{1,2,\ldots,13\} - \{1,2,\ldots,6\}=\{7,..., 13\}\neq\{6,7,..., 13\}$$

subtraction doesn't include the 6 in the result. if you do, you get the equivalent of:
$$\{1,2,\ldots,13\} - \{1,2,\ldots,5\}=\{6,..., 13\}$$

Answer (score 0):

In your example, I would think of Chapter 5 as the "zero" of this operation. Though then again, I doubt any kid, other than perhaps young Sheldon, would care at all about chapters in an Adobe PDF document.

I would use numbered balls or numbered tiles. Then the kids can count for themselves and see if the subset has as many elements as they thought it would.

Comment: I've got compared to sheldon cooper from big bang theory, and am on the autism spectrum, and have played around with LaTeX's chapter feature. I'm in my 30's though.

Comment: @Roddy Well, I hope that's an inaccurate comparison, because I'm guessing they didn't mean it as a compliment.

Comment: restricted interest are music, math, and science. I know it wasn't, it was by family.